# .NETStandard Library 1.6.0 dependency in .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2015
ASP.NET Core application uses class library
ASP.NET Core application and class library had .NET Framework 4.5.2 platform when projects were creating
Class library have .NETStandard Library 1.6.0 dependency
Will this application launch on .NET Core target runtime or it will require full .NET Framework?

Here is some snapshots

[solution explorer of .net core class library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTHJu.png)

[project.json of .net core class library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmVgq.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library .NET Core 1.0 implements .NET Standard 1.6.

So yes, your .NET Standard 1.6 library is compatible with .NET Core applications. The .NET 4.5.2 application will *not* work with it however, as no .NET framework version has implemented 1.6 yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to your attached screenshots, your class library will only be compatible with .NET Core and will not require with .NET Framework.

By the way, it's important to understand the distinction between **NETStandard.Library**, the NuGet package and **".NET Standard"**, the target framework.

*In a nutshell:*

**.NET Standard**, the target framework, is a API spec. A project that only targets netstandard1.6 isn't a .NET Core app yet. Here's a very useful analogy: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/8939f305567e1755412d6dc0b8baf1b7

**NETStandard.Library** is a package https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/1.6.0. This is actually a metapackage i.e. it contains dozens of other packages like System.Collections.Generic and System.Console. These provide the C# compiler with info about what is in .NET Standard (the API spec) so that it knows which APIs you can use. This means can add "NETStandard.Library v1.6.0" as a dependency to more than just .NET Standard 1.6.

Also, FYI - if you use Visual Studio 2017 and csproj instead of project.json, you don't need to list NETStandard.Library in your project file. It's automatically available.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, I did the following to the NetStandard 1.6.1 project's `csproj`:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>

    <!-- BEGIN INSERTION -->

    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>

    <!-- END INSERTION -->

  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="[some stuff here]" Version="[some stuff here]" />
    <PackageReference Include="[some stuff here]" Version="[some stuff here]" />
    <PackageReference Include="[some stuff here]" Version="[some stuff here]" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="[some stuff here]" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```